# Existe algun canal en español?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Me gustaria un canal en español, si alguien se anima estupendo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261283/existe-algun-canal-en-espa%C3%B1ol?/) by [mag.rod](https://answers.ros.org/users/30299/mag.rod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, there is none. Please stick to english.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1